# counter if click the button +1

Tags: java, button, if-statement, count, counter

i need a counter that count +1 when clicks the button. I got this code, counter works fine, but only at the first click. After that, nothing count on click...pls help...thanks

```
  bSpravne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      a = tym.screen;
      b = nova.tcounter;
      if(a <= b) {
         a++;
      }     
      else
      {
         a =1;
      }
         nahodnyTym.setText("Hraje tým" + a);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What are tym.screen and nova.tcounter? Just make something simple like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

         a++;

         nahodnyTym.setText("Hraje tým" + a);
    }
```

Comment: a nedd too, if a reaches max value (b), start count from beginning (1)

Comment: Well, every time you click onClick() method runs and a,b are instantiated again taking the value from tym.screen and nova.tcounter at every click. You should move those lines outside the onclickListener